# Repeating AsyncTask.execute()

Tags: android, android-asynctask

My application contains a long loop which calculates many values within my UIThread and subsequently draws them onscreen.

If I were to offload the calculation loop onto a separate thread using `AsyncTask`, I would be unable to run MyAsyncTask.execute() multiple times as according to the documentation: "The task can be executed only once". When I attempted to run the code I was able to see a single frame drawn but then an exception was thrown: "Cannot execute the task: the task has already been executed (a task can be executed only once)".

It would *not* be a good idea to create a new `AsyncTask` object during each iteration of the draw loop, so is there any way to reuse the same AsyncTask object to run MyAsyncTask.execute() again? Or if not, what would be a more appropriate method to use? Can other forms of threads achieve this?

Comment: What exactly do you do in that for loop?

Comment: why wouldn't it be a good idea to create new task for each iteration ? also, why don't you do the loop inside the asynctask ? it takes an array of items as parameter

Comment: @Luksprog It evaluates a postfix maths expression (such as 5, 7, *). It repeats the process a few hundred times with different values and seems to be quite slow.

Comment: @njzk2 I would be allocating memory to create a new object each time the screen is drawn to, thus causing rapid garbage collection. Or am I mistaken? I am trying to do the calculations loop inside the AsyncTask. I essentially tell the loop how many times it needs to iterate, the thread does its separate thing and it returns an array of the answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create AsyncTask class object each time when you want to excute.

Example

```
    Task _task=new Task();
    _task.excute();
```

For More Info Read This Tutorial [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531950/how-to-execute-async-task-repeatedly-after-fixed-time-intervals)