# Running doInBackground repeatedly in android asynchTask

Tags: android, user-interface, background-process

I want to repeatedly fetch users from database in specific intervals and then do something with them on UI. I know that asynchTask can only be executed once but I want to it to run repeatedly to fetch fresh users' data. I am wondering is there any way to do this, i.e. fetch users after a specific interval repeatedly and then do something with them on UI ???
Is this valid code..

```
while(true) {
new plottingTask().execute("");
Thread.sleep(10000);
}
```

Comment: CountDown Timer and a for Loop will solve your Problem

Comment: Use a `Service`, the complexity of maintaining a framework of `AsyncTask` will quickly outweigh the initial implementation effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this question: [How to execute Async task repeatedly after fixed time intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531950/how-to-execute-async-task-repeatedly-after-fixed-time-intervals)

It has already been asked several times.

A infinite loop is not a good way to go!

If you want to fetch data even if your `Activity` is in background/or not running, a `Service` would be the better way.

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        MyAsyncTask MyTask = new MyAsyncTask ();
        MyTask.execute();

        return Service.START_STICKY; // if android our the user kills the Service it will restart 
    }
}

    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // do your long/network operation
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            // send Intent to BroadcastReceiver in MainActivity.class to know the service  finished its task once
            Intent finished = new Intent("yourPackage.DOWNLOADCOMPLETE");
            sendBroadcast(finished);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        }
    }
}
```

In your MainActivity add a BroadcastReceiver:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ResponseReceiver.ACTION_RESP);
    filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    receiver = new ResponseReceiver();
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
}

// notify when operation in Service finished
private ResponseReceiver receiver;

public class ResponseReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String ACTION_RESP = "yourPackage.DOWNLOADCOMPLETE";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // do stuff if Service finished its task at least once
    }
}
```

Start the Servive every 60 seconds using AlarmManager:

```
// refresh every 60 seconds in MyService.java
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Intent  intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);

AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
// Start every 60 seconds
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 60*1000, pintent);

startService(intent);
```

In your AndroidManifest.xml you have to register the Service:

```
<service
    android:enabled="true"
    android:name=".MyService"
    android:label="your Service Name"> 
</service>
```

`android:label="your Service Name"` will be displayed if you navigate to running apps in android.