# Constantly change TextView while microphone is on

Tags: android, textview, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

I am trying to have my application start to record sound from the microphone when a button is pressed. I want it to print out the amplitude of the sound recorded while the microphone is on to my `TextView` object.

Here is my code for the `RecordSound` class:

```
import android.media.MediaRecorder;

public class RecordSound {
private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;

public void start() {
    if (mRecorder == null) {
        mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        mRecorder.setOutputFile("/dev/null");

        try {
            mRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mRecorder.start();
    }
}

public void stop() {
    if (mRecorder != null) {
        mRecorder.stop();
        mRecorder.release();
        mRecorder = null;
    }
}

public double getAmplitude() {
    if (mRecorder != null) {
        return mRecorder.getMaxAmplitude();
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

public boolean isOn() {
    if (mRecorder == null) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

Here is my code for the `MainActivity` class:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private RecordSound mRecorder = null;
private TextView tv = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button recordButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRecord);
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.data);
    mRecorder = new RecordSound();

    recordButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mRecorder.isOn()) {
                mRecorder.stop();
            }
            else {
                mRecorder.start();
            }

            if (mRecorder.isOn()) {
//                  long t= System.currentTimeMillis();
//                  long end = t+15000;
//                  while(System.currentTimeMillis() < end) {
//                      tv.setText(String.valueOf(mRecorder.getAmplitude()));
//                  }
//                  
                tv.setText(String.valueOf(mRecorder.getAmplitude()));
            }
        }
    });

    while (mRecorder != null && mRecorder.isOn()) {
        tv.setText(String.valueOf(mRecorder.getAmplitude()));
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

The code that is commented out is my attempt at making the microphone record and print the amplitude for the first fifteen seconds that the microphone is on.

Currently I am able to press the button to start recording. It will then print out the amplitude value to the `TextView`, but it is always `0.0`. I've tried a `while` statement several different places, both in and out of the `onClick()` method. I can't seem to get the `TextView` to update dynamically while the microphone is recording sound.

Comment: You have to explain your issue to provide suggestion/fix

Comment: @Jack Rather than linking to a third party website like codeshare, you should embed the most relevant code into your posts. Also, there isn't any code provided in the second link.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really try to run your code and I don't know much about MediaRecoder in Android. But I guess the problem of your code is that your `while` loop is inside `onCreate()` method, and so the loop only runs when the `onCreate()` is called (in case of you haven't understood when Android system calls `onCreate()` method of your app, I suggest reading the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#Lifecycle) document). Clearly, your media recorder hasn't been started when the `while` loop runs, so this statment:

```
tv.setText(String.valueOf(mRecorder.getAmplitude()));
```

is not runned at all.

Then when you press the button for the first time, the media recoder is started and right after that, you get the amplitude, set the `TextView` value also for the first and only one time. The document of `MediaRecorder.getMaxAmplitude()` says that it returns

> the maximum absolute amplitude measured since the last call, or 0 when
>   called for the first time

That's why you always get `0.0` display on the TextView.

In order to update the TextView dynamically while the microphone is on, you should maintain a background thread that check the media recoder and get amplitude periodically. For this purpose, you can consider using `Timer` and `TimerTask`. But since Android system doesn't allow you to update the UI from any thread other than the main thread, you may have to use `Handler`. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6532298/1275831) is useful for you.