# Communication Between Web application and Android Application

Tags: android, web, communication

I've a web application and an android application. Now I want my web application to communicate with the mobile application when a specific event is triggered on the web application. How can I achieve this? We can communicate with web application from mobile app using web-services but I want Web Application to communicate with Android Application.

Comment: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java

Comment: Is there a way to build a resp api on android app, so my web app will request data to android app, is the inverse not app to server, is the server to app requests

Comment: We cannot build a Rest API on android app which server can access, but, you can implement the WebSocket on the backend and in your android application. Using websocket server can communicate with the mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is You can create web service and hit to server every 5 seconds to check if any response from server. its not that quick but you can achieve what you want.

refer this

[Send request to web service every 5 second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26058424/send-request-to-web-service-every-5-second)

Comment: Thanks ganesh101. This was the first thought came into my mind, but it will cause the battery to discharge.

Comment: Is there a way to build a resp api on android app, so my web app will request data to android app, is the inverse not app to server, is the server to app requests