# How to make a retrofit call every second using LiveData?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, androidx, android-livedata

I am dealing with a youtube api to fetch subscriber count of channel, now as the subscriber count change every second I need to make the retrofit call every second. I am using android Jetpack components in my application, I want to know how to update the livedata every second, i.e. making the retrofit call every second.

Currently my application works fine using a Handler, Runnable and

```
handler.postDelayed(this, 1000)
```

But this handler uses UI thread, which is not good.

I have created a repository class and view model class.

Comment: you can easily call any retrofit request from UI thread but the idea of doing that every second sounds crazy to me

Comment: @pskink do you have a better solution, i have explained my case...

Comment: i already said: `"you can easily call any retrofit request from UI thread"`- this is perfectly ok to call retrofit request from UI thread

Comment: i have no much experience with retrofit `Callback`s but 5 minute googling gives [callbackExecutor](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Retrofit.Builder.html#callbackExecutor-java.util.concurrent.Executor-)

Comment: Every second? You really should consider using a solution that doesn't drain the user's network quota. It is not free, you know.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options like AsyncTask, Timer, Service, AlarmManger.
Take a look at these questions:

[Scheduling recurring task in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376470/scheduling-recurring-task-in-android)

[Send request to web service every 5 second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26058424/send-request-to-web-service-every-5-second)