# Android -imageview showing old images download from URL

Tags: android

this is the code I'm using.

link contain image
http://mycapturetest.byethost17.com/Screen.jpg

when i update image on URl and open it on browser. it shows updated image.

but when open the same link in android application it keep showing the last image uploaded on the URl. (Not the new one)

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;



    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
        bmImage.setImageDrawable(null);
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(null);
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

               bmImage.setImageDrawable(null);
               bmImage.setImageBitmap(null);
               bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "set....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }
}
```

Comment: m calling function in oncreate() method like

  new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1))
        .execute("http://mycapturetest.byethost17.com/Screen.jpg");

Comment: I suggest you to use this library https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader  . It's the best to me.

Comment: any solution with out using library ?

Comment: the problem seems is the caching..but if you use that library you will not have any problem. Trust me. it's easy to use and the best way. You can found several tutorials about that.

Comment: its working but how to do it repeatedly like i wanna update image after 5 seconds

Comment: create a timer in your task that runs every 5 seconds

Comment: using 
        ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.displayImage(url, img,defaultOptions);

still getting old image

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off caching of resources loaded from URLs using the `URLConnection` class:

```
    try {
        URLConnection connection = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openConnection();
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
        mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: its working but how to do it repeatedly like i wanna update image after 5 seconds

Comment: schedule your DownloadImageTask to run at repeat intervals. see the answer to this question for how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531950/how-to-execute-async-task-repeatedly-after-fixed-time-intervals