# How make a regurlary task in a android thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I try to make an asynctask that can regularly get the code of a web page.
I can do this one time with doInBackground method but I can not execute several times :/

Can you help me please ?

Thanks

Comment: Please improve your question to meet the [mcve] requirements. Learning [ask] is key to getting the response you desire.

Comment: You will find your answer here :- http://stackoverflow.com/a/6532298/1384010

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned here: [Repeat a task with a time delay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242268/repeat-a-task-with-a-time-delay/6242292#6242292) you should use the `Handler` class :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use AlarmManger's setRepeating method to trigger an IntentService periodically.

Answer (score 0):

I got a good example here, 
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/use-androids-alarmmanager-to-schedule-an-event/

use

```
AlarmManager.setRepeating() insted AlarmManager.set()
```

like

```
AlarmManager.setRepeating( AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() , 2500 ,pi );
```

where 2500 is interval time in Milliseconds