# Best way to perform a background Thread repeatedly in Android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, usb

I need to read data constantly from USB (*50ms interval at least*) and update several `View`'s at the same time.

Updating `View`'s can be quite easily achieved by using a `Handler`, but since USB reading performs too much work and there's no need to touch the UI Thread, it has to be done on a different thread.

I have read a few questions [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531950/how-to-execute-async-task-repeatedly-after-fixed-time-intervals) about executing `AsyncTask` repeatedly but please correct me if I'm wrong: it seems it's not a good way to go.

What are the best ways to execute background work *repeatedly* in Android?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need some finer grained control on the time elapsed, I suggest you start a separate thread with a loop, and use [Thread.sleep](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)) to wait before polling. When you have something new, dispatch it with the Handler to the UI thread.

Something like this (rough sketch, should give you an idea):

```
    new Thread() {
        private boolean stop = false;

        @Override public void run() {
            while (!stop) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // poll the USB and dispatch changes to the views with a Handler
            }
        }

        public void doStop() {
            stop = true;
        }
    };
```