# how to call webservices at fixed interval?

Tags: android, web-services

What is the best way for calling webservices or Restful api at fixed interval of time in android using asyncTask or Volley? Currently I'm using timertask to handle my restful api call at fixed interval.

Comment: `Timertask` is best option for that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531950/how-to-execute-async-task-repeatedly-after-fixed-time-intervals

Comment: webservices or Restful api calling using `TimerTask` is best when app is open. Need to call api in background use `IntentService` and restart this service using `AlarmManager`