# Java android ava.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, android

In this line :

```
 while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(content)) != -1) {
```

This line is inside in astyntask

in logs I see this :

```
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:492)
 W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
 W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:241)
 W/System.err:     at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:162)
 W/System.err:     at pl.eltegps.teminalmobile.Activity.MainActivity$connectTask3.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1353)
 W/System.err:     at pl.eltegps.teminalmobile.Activity.MainActivity$connectTask3.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1205)
 W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
 W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
 W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: Your question is missing the actual exception thrown - it's the line in the log just before the first one you pasted.

Comment: @NimrodArgov in logs I only see this

Comment: Can you post more of your code? How you execute this `AsyncTask`? Are you executing it only once or multiple times?

Comment: @pleft multiple times I execute this astyntask  https://paste.ofcode.org/mU2GmpSwshxaxbzDbS9hXf

Answer (score 1):

[`AsyncTask`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) documentation has some threading rules:

**Threading rules**

> There are a few threading rules that must be followed for this class
>   to work properly:
>
> - The AsyncTask class must be loaded on the UI thread. This is done automatically as of JELLY_BEAN.
> - **The task instance must be created on the UI thread.**
> - **execute(Params...) must be invoked on the UI thread.**
> - Do not call onPreExecute(), onPostExecute(Result), doInBackground(Params...), onProgressUpdate(Progress...) manually.
> - **The task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a second execution is attempted.)**

You cannot execute multiple times the same task, only once.

**UPDATE**

In your "paste.ofcode.org" url it seems that you break 3 rules of the threading rules above (boldly marked)

Rules 2&3 break here, (why start a new thread to execute an `AsyncTask`?):

```
thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new connectTask3().execute();
            }
        };
        thread.start();
```

Do not create a new `thread`, instead delete the above code and replace it with just:

```
new connectTask3().execute();
```

Comment: Ok but I don't use this same object I create a new object and I do execute

Comment: Can you update your answer and post the relevant code to see how the asynctask is instantiated and executed?

Comment: Please dont paste urls, update your question and post the code there. The url in your comment is the asynctask itself and it is huge and badly formatted, I cannot check if there is another class inside there, we need to see how it is called in your `MainActivity`. Please update your question and post the code of your `MainActivity`

Comment: Now I see that you execute multiple times the asynctask from inside `onPostExecute` of the same asynctask via a `TimerTask` and from the last url, you start a new thread to execute the asynctask. If you read my answer rule number 3 says to execute the task from the UI thread, so creating a new thread to execute it doesn't seem correct. Please I will not reply anymore to posting urls, update your question with the relevant pieces of code. thank you

Comment: Can you tell me how it should look like?

Comment: For the TImerTask code part check here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6532298/3635454 For running the task from a new thread, just instantiate and execute the task outside of this thread (I will update my answer in a minute)

Comment: I replece my TImer to callAsynchronousTask and I dn't create a new thread but sometimes i have this same error

Comment: Then use a `service` instead of an `AsyncTask` see the comments in the link I provided in my comment above

Comment: Can I use in service AsynTask ?

Comment: Just read a tutorial please, see: https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/index.html